# Deleting contents of a file in Tcl

Tags: file, file-io, permissions, tcl

I'm having some troubles deleting the contents of a text file. From what I can tell, I cannot seem to rename or delete this file and create a new one with the same name, due to permission issues with the PLM software we use. Unfortunately, I am on my own here, since no one seems to know what exactly is wrong.

I can read and write to this file, however. So I've been looking at the [seek](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1498) command and doing something like this:

```
set f [open "C:/John/myFile.txt" "a+"]

seek $f 0   
set fp [tell $f]

seek $f 0 end
set end [tell $f]

# Restore current file pointer
seek $f $fp

while { $fp < $end } {
    puts -nonewline $f " "
    incr fp
}

close $f
```

This seems to replace all the lines with spaces, but I'm not sure this is the correct way to approach this. Can someone give me some pointers? I'm still relatively new to Tcl.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

If you've got at least Tcl 8.5, open the file in `r+` or `w+` mode (experimentation may be required) and then use [`chan truncate`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/chan.htm#M40):

```
chan truncate $f 0
```

If you're using 8.4 or before, you have instead to do this (and it only works for truncating to empty):

```
close [open $thefilename "w"]
```

(The `w` mode creates the file if it doesn't exist, and truncates it to empty on open if it does. The rest of the program might or might not like this!)

Note however that this does not reset where other channels open on the file think they are. This can lead to strange effects (such as writing at a large offset, with the OS filling out the preceding bytes with zeroes) even without locking.

Comment: Also, avoid the `a` and `a+` modes when doing this sort of thing; those have some special semantics associated with them which doesn't mix too well with truncation. (Especially on Windows, which is _very_ non-POSIX in this area.)

Answer (score 3):

```
close [open $path w]
```

And voila, an empty file. If this file does not yet exist, it will be created.

Answer (score 1):

A really easy way to do this is to just over-write your file with an empty file. For example create an empty file (you can do this manually or using the following TCL code):

```
set blank_file [open "C:/tmp/blank.txt" "w"]
close $blank_file
```

Then just over-write your original file with the blank file as follows:

```
file rename -force "C:/tmp/blank.txt" "C:/John/myFile.txt"
```

Of course, you may have permissions problems if something else has grabbed the file.

Answer (score 0):

You say the file is opened exclusively with another process but you can write to it ?! I think you have permission problems. Are you using Linux or Unix ?! (It seems it is a Windows system but permission problems usually occur on Linux/Unix systems, It is weird, isn't it ?!)

The file is not exclusively opened if you are able to read and write to it and you may have no appropriate permission to delete the file.

Also it is better to test the code on a file you know you have all permissions on it. If the code is working you can focus on your target file. Also you can Google for 'how to file operations in Tcl'. Read this [Manipulating Files With Tcl](http://www2.lib.uchicago.edu/keith/tcl-course/topics/tcl-files.html)

Comment: Ok, I see now that my wording was unclear. The file is opened with another process, but the Tcl script that reads and writes to the file is also in that same process. It's just that I can only read and write, but not rename or delete. The whole "permissions denied" is the error message I get when I try to rename or delete the file from within this process.

Comment: So if you're in the same process which has exclusively opened the file, there should be no problem. You just need to know how to manipulate files in Tcl.

Comment: Do you want to delete or rename the file ?! Or you want to read and write to file ?! File remains open because a handler is assigned to the file and you application is holing it. When the application releases the handler, file will be freed and closed.

Comment: I want to delete the contents of the file. The first option I tried is to simply delete the file and create another with the same name, and this is where I ran into permission issues with the PLM software we use, despite the fact that I have admin privileges. So what I tried next was to overwrite the contents of each line.

Comment: So you can seek 0 and go to first of the file. And write data without any problem. You will write on previous data. Also keep a counter and delete what is remaining after that counter when the application is closing to make the file correct.